# Is NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder able to validate a connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a .Net 5 application and want to add Ef Core with Postgres support. I want to validate the database connection string coming from `IConfiguration`. Based on this question

[How to check is connection string valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412983/how-to-check-is-connection-string-valid)

I know that builders inheriting from `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` check the connection string in the constructor. So I created a demo code how the validation could look like

```
bool Validate(IConfiguration options)
{
    try
    {
        string databaseConnectionString = options.GetConnectionString("Database");
        _ = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(databaseConnectionString);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I had a look at the `NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder`

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.html

and see that it does not inherit from the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`. It does not provide a method to validate a connection string.

Does someone know if that class performs a connection string validation when constructing the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlConnectionStringBuilder is the SqlClient connection string builder, so specific to Microsoft's SQL Server database. Both SqlConnectionStringBuilder and NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder derive from DbConnectionStringBuilder, which is the database-agnostic base class.

And yes, NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder validates the string - you can give it a try with a bad connection string. However, this doesn't guarantee that connecting will actually succeed - just the that connection-string is well-formed and doesn't try to use unsupported options, etc. Consider just trying to open a connection instead.

Comment: Why does `NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder` allow you to pass an empty or null `connectionString` to the ctor and not validate it?

Comment: You can pass an empty string, but you'll get an exception when you attempt to open the connection. This is similar to instantiating an NpgsqlConnection without passing any connection string - it's just the initial state of the object.