# How we get local SQL Server instance through c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a Windows app in which I need to create a connection string automatically. I create a Windows form similar to SQL Server Management Studio Connect to server form. For this I need few things

1. local SQL server Name of the system.
2. After user fill the form like select server Name and authentication type then i need to check that that filled details are correct.
3. I need to create automatic connection string in c# and create automatic database and for this I execute SQL query in c# code that are working fine.

So help me get the instance name and check the data is valid in C# window application.

Answer (score 3):

To get all instances of local network (and local) you can use this code: (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
```

And to test connection string you can simply open a connection with generated connection string. like this: (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434868/1095390) answer)

```
string provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; // for example
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
using(DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection()) {
    conn.ConnectionString = cs;
    conn.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use  [ManagedComputer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi.managedcomputer.aspx),

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;

ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer();

foreach (ServerInstance si in mc.ServerInstances)
{
     Console.WriteLine("The installed instance name is " + si.Name);
}
```

Comment: I've used this namespace right now , but there is an error highlighting under "Management". The error is showing that "This type or namespace does not exist under Microsoft.SqlServer ". Please confirm ! My sql server version is 2008.

Comment: see https://askgarth.com/blog/how-to-install-the-sql-server-wmi-provider/